# Python/numpy append arrays, transpose, and save as csv

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, transpose

What I am doing: generating a series of long 1D arrays.

What I want to do: 
append/concatentate/vstack/? these into a 2D array, then save the rows as columns in a csv file.

The following works, but it's not elegant:

```
rlist=[]                        # create empty list
for i in range(nnn)             # nnn is typically 2000
    (calculate an array "r")
    rlist.append(r)             # append f.p. array to rlist
rarr = array(rlist)             # turn it back into array so I can transpose
numpy.savetxt('test.csv',rarr.T,delimiter=',')  # save rows as columns in csv file
```

Is there a more elegant or pythonesque way to do it?

Comment: Why do you say this is not elegant?  Sure, you could use `numpy.vstack` and a transpose -- But in the end, it will be the same number of lines of code and you'll either be growing the same array at every iteration of the loop (which is likely to be inefficient) or waiting until the end to stack them all together (which is what you're doing now).  I don't see much difference ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the length of `r` and `nnn` in advance, you can do:

```
rarr = np.zeros((r_len, nnn)) # r_len rows, nnn columns
for i in range(nnn):
    rarr[:,i] = r_calc()
numpy.savetxt('test.csv', rarr, delimiter=',')
```

This puts the data vectors directly into rows of `rarr`, saving you the conversion to array and transpose.

Comment: Preallocating the array is a good approach. I'm not sure it is any more elegant, but it is likely to be a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
rarr = np.concatenate([get_array(r) for r in xrange(nnn)])
np.savetxt('test.cvs', rarr.T, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions.  I'm a real Python newbie, so I expect my code to be ugly.  Maybe not as bad as I thought!  I'll work through the ideas.  Excellent way to learn Python, but (coming from FORTRAN) Python's methods aren't alway obvious.